# Winscp SFTP Flat File from local machine to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage, sftp

I have enabled "Require SFTP" on my Azure Blob Storage account.

How do I use Winscp to transfer a csv file on my local machine directly to this Blob Storage account?

I have tried using "SFTP" protocol, host = , port = 22, username and password of my azure account, and the connection keeps timing out.

What should the host/port be? What are the necessary credentials?

Comment: There is no "require SFTP" - there's only the ability to require secure transfer (e.g. https).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible. Azure does not support upload files to Azure storage account by using FTP client. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/397724-allow-to-upload-data-to-azure-blobs-by-a-classic-f).

If you want to upload csv file to Azure Storage account directly, you could use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

Comment: I am finding a way for my data providers to SFTP their flat files to my azure blob storage account using classic clients like Winscp. This is possible?

Comment: @stochastiq Based on my knowledge, it is not possible. Azure storage account is not a FTP service provider. You could use Azure Storage Explorer or Azcopy to upload data to your azure blob storage account.

Comment: @stochastiq  If you use Azure Storage Explorer, it supports upload data to storage account directly. You even could use mouse to do it.

Comment: Thanks very much @Walter - MSFT :)

Comment: Allowing multiple external customers to use Storage Explorer? Unless you limit access with a SAS, you are essentially allowing any customer to do anything with that storage account, with no restrictions - including ability to view and delete content from other data providers. Goes against the grain of the original question, attempting to enable secure data transfer. I can't imagine any scenario where using such a tool is a valid option for external parties.